# changing shapes with accumcomp in biodiversity r?

Tags: r

If possible, I would like to change the default shapes used in the accumcomp function in the Biodiversity R package in R for multiple species accumulation curves. This way the shapes can match the rest of the graphs in my manuscript.

Here is the example text from the package:

`accumcomp(x,y="",factor,scale="",method="exact",permutations=100,
    conditioned=T, gamma="boot",plotit=T,labelit=T,legend=T,rainbow=T,
    xlim=c(1,max),ylim=c(0,rich),type="p",xlab="sites",
    ylab="species richness",...)`

And the code for my graph looks like this:

`accumcomp(fungi, y=fungi.env, factor='Stand.Composition', 
              method='exact', legend=TRUE, conditioned=TRUE,
              ylim=c(0,50),xlim=c(0,110),xlab="Seedlings",ylab="Species 
              richness",rainbow=FALSE,labelit=FALSE)`

fungi: richness values for all the fungi found on my site

fungi.env: indicates if the fungi were found on trees in single or mixed species stands

So, pretty much I just want two curves plotted, which is working, but to change to shapes used. I found that setting rainbow=FALSE lets me change the colors but trying to type in pch=c() gets me this error:

```
Error in accumplot(result1, addit = addit, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, xlim = 
xlim,  : 
formal argument "pch" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

Is it possible to change the shapes for the factors in this function? It seems insane that you can't. I have never come across this problem in any graphing package I have used in R.

Comment: This error means you that you have (somehow) specified ` pch` argument more than once.  The error is coming from `accumplot` function, not from `accumcomp`.  I am not quite sure if you have provided enough information to give a proper answer. Maybe you should recreate this problem using a data available in the `Biodiversity`.

Comment: Hey Suren, Thanks for replying. I based my code off the example from the package:                                                          data(dune.env)
data(dune)
dune.env$site.totals <- apply(dune,1,sum)
Accum.1 <- accumresult(dune, y=dune.env, scale='site.totals', method='exact', conditioned=TRUE)
Accum.1
accumplot(Accum.1)
accumcomp(dune, y=dune.env, factor='Management', method='exact', legend=FALSE, conditioned=TRUE)

Comment: Sorry this wouldn’t let me edit my comment:
I can use pch in accumplot, but would like to use the factor function in accumcomp with the shapes I want.